# Neo4j/Spring Data Neo4j 4 index and case of characters

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have a following SDN 4 node entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Product {

    @Index(unique = false)
    private String name;

...

}
```

Inside of this entity I have added `name` property and declared an index.

Right now I'm going to implement case insensitive search by product name.

I have created a SDN 4 repository method:

```
@Query("MATCH (p:Product) WHERE LOWER(d.name) = LOWER({name}) RETURN p")
Product findByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

In order to search a product I use following Cypher: `LOWER(d.name) = LOWER({name})`

I think the index doesn't effectively work in this case because I lowercase the strings.

What is a proper way in Neo4j/SDN 4 to make index working here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need to store the name in the original case, then convert the name to lowercase before storing it in the DB.

If you do need the name in the original case, then you could add an extra property (say, "lower_name") that stores the lowercased name. You can index that property and use it for indexed comparisons.

A third choice is to use [legacy indexing](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing.html), which is much more complex to use and no longer favored. However, it does support case-insensitive indexing (see the second example on [this page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wondering or it is the only way to achive it with Neo4j and SDN 4. For example in PostgreSQL we can create `CREATE INDEX lower_case_name ON users ((lower(name))); `and then use it. Do we have something similar at Neo4j/SDN ?

Comment: That type of feature does not exist. However, see my updated answer for a third option.